# Why can't I create and execute functions in my passport.js local strategy callback?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js

When I try calling `saveTheUsr()` it results in an error saying `usr is not defined`. I just don't get it and why it is not accessible? I know I can simply exclude the function and have the functions contents in the callback and it would work. I just want to know a way that I can declare the usr object and call that through a function in the callback. Exactly the way I tried in my callback. Is that possible? and why does my method not work?

```js
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../app/models/user');

function saveTheUsr(){
  var usr = new User();
  usr.local.email    = email;
  usr.local.password = password;
  usr.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
        throw err;
      return done(null, usr);
  });
}

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {

        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

            if (err)
                return done(err);

            if (user) {
                return done(null, false);
            } else {
                saveTheUsr();
            }

        });

    }));
```

Comment: ```saveTheUsr()``` method out of your scope, you need to send ```email``` and ```password``` as a param to that method like this ```saveTheUsr(email, password)```

Comment: It seems like `done` could be undefined as well. Care to update your question with the stack trace? You need to pass `done` to `saveTheUsr()` and update the function to take in `done`. Try that first and let us know whether it works for you or not

Comment: Oh yup, after adding in done as the parameter it works! Thx so much!

Comment: @EllyBolson - thanks for confirming the issue. I have raised an answer for you to close this issue. Will greatly appreciate it if you can click on the tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As pointed in the comment.**

The issue was with the `done` variable not being defined in the `saveTheUsr()` function. And the fix for it would be to make `saveTheUsr` accept an extra parameter called `done` and pass a callback function for places that calls it.